# Vim doesn't refresh screen when going fullscreen

Tags: terminal

I've just upgraded to a new laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 and installed Vim 7.4 1-1952.

I installed most of my plugins when I noticed that 80% of the time when I press <kbd>F11</kbd> to go fullscreen, Vim doesn't "update"/redraw unless I press a button or click on the screen. Here's a photo of what happens when I press <kbd>F11</kbd>:

[image]

I've tried disabling my plugins to see if one of them might be the issue. I realized that this only happens when I have some sort of syntactic-checker enabled such as YouCompleteMe or syntastic.

Again, the issue resolves itself immediately once I press *any* button but I can't figure out what could be causing it. I don't have the same problem anywhere else aside from Vim.

EDIT: This only occurs with Full Screen, Pressing  CTRL + ALT + Numpad in order to maximize the **window** works just fine.
EDIT2: This also seems to occur with neovim

Comment: Vim has an event loop.  It doesn't redraw asynchronously when it receives a `SIGWINCH`.

Comment: Did you tried `:redraw ` or pressed `ctrl+L`?

Comment: @SibiCoder From the question: _the issue resolves itself immediately once I press any button but I can't figure out what could be causing it_.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed it in a very peculiar way, and have no idea how you'd figure this out.

In Ubuntu, go to

- **System Settngs**
- **Appearance**
- **Behaviour**  and then
- **Show the menus for a window**
- check **In the window's title bar** .

The problem seems to be fixed now, but I'm guessing it's still a bug in vim or some plugin.

Comment: I don't think so.  This sounds like a bug with the terminal or your shell.  Have you tried using a different terminal?

Comment: I tried using terminator and got the same results.  I should note that apparently vim-airline makes the bug appear again.